# Custom aggregation functions in angular ui-grid header get non-numeric value

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, aggregation, ui-grid

It's easy to do count, min, max for the aggregate functions, but I would like to get string concat value in the grouped row.

What kind of custom function/aggregator I can write to aggregate string values?

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableFiltering: true,
    treeRowHeaderAlwaysVisible: false,
    columnDefs: [
      { name: 'name', width: '30%' },
      { name: 'gender', sort: { priority: 1, direction: 'asc' }, width: '20%', cellFilter: 'mapGender' },
      { name: 'age', treeAggregationType: uiGridGroupingConstants.aggregation.MAX, width: '20%' },
      { name: 'company', width: '25%' },
      { name: 'registered', width: '40%', cellFilter: 'date', type: 'date' },
      { name: 'state', grouping: { groupPriority: 0 }, sort: { priority: 0, direction: 'desc' }, width: '35%', cellTemplate: '<div><div ng-if="!col.grouping || col.grouping.groupPriority === undefined || col.grouping.groupPriority === null || ( row.groupHeader && col.grouping.groupPriority === row.treeLevel )" class="ui-grid-cell-contents" title="TOOLTIP">{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</div></div>' },
      { name: 'balance', width: '25%', cellFilter: 'currency', treeAggregationType: uiGridGroupingConstants.aggregation.AVG, customTreeAggregationFinalizerFn: function( aggregation ) {
        aggregation.rendered = aggregation.value;
      } }
    ],
    onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
```

Here is plunkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/KVq7vC9cFb7uNc9edLYj?p=preview

Currently, it's grouped on State and gives aggregated value max and sum for two columns Age and Balance respectively. I want to display grouped Gender row value as "Male, Female". How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve it on my own, here is the custom function to add concat or conditional string value return -

```
     { name: 'company', width: '25%',
        customTreeAggregationFn : function( aggregation, fieldValue, numValue, row ) {
          if(!aggregation.value){
           aggregation.value = row.entity.company;
          }
        },
        customTreeAggregationFinalizerFn: function( aggregation ) {
         aggregation.rendered = aggregation.value;
        }
      }
```

Plunkr link to the solution - http://plnkr.co/edit/KVq7vC9cFb7uNc9edLYj?p=preview